# Unable to save workbook in SharePoint Online / Office 365

Tags: excel, excel-services

We have a team site with a document library with 4 excel documents in it. When we want to edit the document using the Excel online editor we get an error: "Unable to save workbook". The changes are not saved.
[image: Unable to save workbook]

When I move the document to another library on another site collection I can edit the document. Move the document to a library in the same site gives us the same "unable to save workbook" error.

Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at some of the Technet discussions where others have same issue. One of the suggestion was to ensure that the file name does not have any special character. Another was to reset IIS. May be this would help you.

Comment: Reset IIS is not really an option in SharePoint Online though :)

Comment: thank you for your comment Edwin. Reset is indeed no option on SharePoint Online ;-)

Comment: the filename is plain and simple. When I moved it to another teamsite it worked fine.